# Using Blogger V3 API in PHP

Tags: php, api, google-api, blogger, blogspot

so I have done extensive research on this topic, and after doing more research have tried more solutions but I am still having issues.

There seems to be no updated solutions for this problem.

I would love to use the blogger v3 api with PHP but I am having some problems. All I want to do is be able to make a post, but I am still having more issues.

For example even this simple code doesn't work.

```
<?php
$blogID = 'xxx'; 
$apikey = 'xxx';

$requestURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/{$blogID}?key={$apikey}";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($requestURL));

echo $requestURL;

var_dump($json);

?>
```

It displays the json as "NULL" I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: If you go to the URL, does it show valid JSON?

Comment: Hello when I go to the url that has the proper key and blogger ID I receive what seems to be a working response. 

http://prntscr.com/6gtdnz


Thank you for the help it is much appreciated by the way. This is an issue that has really been driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you print out the undecoded `file_get_contents` results? If it's the expected JSON, have you used [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to get any errors in the JSON parsing process?

Comment: Hello 

file_get_contents($requestURL);
//$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($requestURL));

var_dump($json);

Outputs as null

Comment: The output now seems to be bool(false)

Comment: I have changed my php.ini config ; Whether to allow the treatment of URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On

Comment: The problem seemed to be the use of file_get_contents.

Comment: I am now returning some JSON data, what is the next step to making a post on the blog?

Comment: Next step is reading the documentation.

Comment: I have read the documentation I am just not sure how to integrate it into php. 

POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8070105920543249955/posts/
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "8070105920543249955"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}

Comment: That is from the google documentations how do i get OAuth 2.0 Token, is it the same as an API key?

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way ceejayoz it is appreciated.

Comment: I have read the documentation it seems to make posts you have to use OAuth 2.0 Token but that requires some logging in by the user?

Comment: I want to make posts to my blog without any need for users to do any action.